# How to mass-delete inline styles in Wordpress custom post type automatically?

Tags: functions, customization

I'm looking for a pragmatic way to delete about 100+ individual pages worth of inline styles. I had entered in content for a client by copying and pasting from Word, which took all that data with it and wrapped it in inline styles. It doesn't make sense to go through each post individually. Has anyone done this before? I would be fine with any solution that 'works.'

Myself and my employer thank you for any input immensely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [Search Regex plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/).  It will allow you to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to find and replace (in your case *delete*) inline styles.  Make sure you backup your database before you begin!

A simple regular expression that should work for you would be

```
(style=").*"
```

It will look for a string starting with `style="` and containing any number of characters until it hits another double quote `"`.  (That would be an inline style applied to an HTML element).  You'll "replace" it with an empty value (to delete it).

You can also test your content / regular expression with [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) to ensure the one I gave you will work.

**Backup your database** before you begin. If something goes wrong you can restore it.  It looks like this plugin will allow you to Search (as a test) before you run a Replace & Save.

Comment: I found this solution helpful but `style=("|\')(.*?)("|\')` was a better query that caught fewer false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) anytime you need to do bulk operations on posts without making it available through a traditional interface. For your case, you'd want to register a command similar to the sample below, which will iterate through all of your posts of type 'your_post_type':

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'WP_CLI' ) ) return;

/**
 * Basic structure for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/161963/13937
 *
 * @package wp-cli
 */
class Wpse161963_Command extends WP_CLI_Command {

  /**
   * Clean posts
   *
   * ## OPTIONS
   *
   * ## EXAMPLES
   *
   * wp wpse161963 scrub
   *
   */
  public function scrub( $args, $assoc_args ) {
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

      // Scrub the post content and save the results

      // Print a success message
      WP_CLI::success( sprintf( __( 'Post "%s" has been scrubbed!', 'wpse161963' ), $post->post_title );

    }
  }

}

WP_CLI::add_command( 'wpse161963', 'Wpse161963_Command' );
```

Note that this is just an example, but it should be enough to put you on the right track.